# Friending a dependent argument template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it a bug or I still don't know something about templates? If so, why it ends up like this and what can be done?

If I remove the first two forward declarations, I get the same error in the place of BARef definition.

```c
template<typename T, 
         unsigned int blockInitSize, 
         unsigned int blockMaxSize>
struct BAInternalIndex;

template<typename T,
         unsigned int blockInitSize, 
         unsigned int blockMaxSize,
         BAInternalIndex<T, blockInitSize, blockMaxSize>* (&getIndexPointer) (const T&)>
class BARef;

template<typename T, 
         unsigned int blockInitSize, 
         unsigned int blockMaxSize>
struct BAInternalIndex
{
    template<typename T2, 
             unsigned int blockInitSize2, 
             unsigned int blockMaxSize2,
             BAInternalIndex<T2, blockInitSize2, blockMaxSize2>* (&getIndexPointer2) (const T2&)>
    friend class BARef;
};

error C3855: 'BARef': template parameter 'getIndexPointer' is incompatible with the declaration
```

Tried to compile with Visual C++ 9.0 and 11.0.

---

Minimal example / SSC(n)CE:

```
template<typename T>
struct A;

template<typename T, void(&fun)(A<T>)>
class B;

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename T2, void(&fun)(A<T2>)>
    friend class B;                                // line 11
};                                                 // line 12

int main()
{
    A<int> a;                                      // line 16
}
```

VS2010 (v10) error output:

```
(line 11) error C3855: `B`: template parameter `fun` is incompatible with the
                            declaration
(line 12)              see reference to class template instantiation `A` being
                       compiled

(line 11) error C3855: `B`: template parameter `fun` is incompatible with the
                            declaration
(line 16)              see reference to class template instantiation `A` being
                       compiled
                       with
                       [
                           `T=int`
                       ]
```

Comment: Compiler? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? (Because it seems to compile fine on [clang++3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1d0e171f6a9e882c).)

Comment: @DyP, Visual 9 and 11

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, may I insert a minimal example in your question?

Comment: @DyP, sure. / I'm actually condemned to Visual C++. This code needs to work in a dll, which needs to work with a Visual-compiled application, which heavily refuse to cooperate with code compiled with anything else then one version of VC.

Comment: Might be related to those bugs: [548558](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/548558/template-parameter-is-incompatible-with-the-declaration), [731937](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/731937/friend-template-bug-in-msvc), [548558](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/548558/template-parameter-is-incompatible-with-the-declaration)

Comment: @DyP, they said for 548558 a workaround is removing the default argument, so I think it is not this. But by looking at those bugs and thinking they are from for 10th and 11th major versions of the compiler, I have a feeling the case is MS itself.